# Reynolds number of a submerged jet

Tags: dimensional-analysis, flow, viscosity, fluid-dynamics

Considering a jet of gas A into quiescent gas B how would the Reynolds number be defined? The characteristic lenght is the diameter of the jet. The velocity is also obvious. But what about the viscosity? Should one consider the viscosity of gas A (the gas of the jetz) or gas B (the quiescent gas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the fluids can be taken as inmiscible during the process, since otherwise the viscosity of the mixture would come into play. In such a case, the lowest viscosity will determine the Re. For instance, it will determine the appearance of instabilities and the complexity of the turbulence produced around the jet boundary layer.

You can think of it by taking the argument to the limit: what would be the reynolds number for a case where one of the fluids has $\nu \rightarrow \infty$, making it practically a solid? Would you not consider the other fluid as the reference?

Nonetheless, one could consider also the two separate Reynolds numbers, which would apply to the motion each of the fluids in their own domain. But in this case it would be the representative size that would be less clear, in particular away from the base of the jet, where the two fluids have strated to mix. There a more detailed analysis would be required that took the characteristic scales of the various intrusions into account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer so far. This leads to a couple of follow up questions though: Just as you stated, I assumed the gases to be immisicible so far. For the base of the jet i feel this is a justified assumption. But what about further away from the base? In general I would assume gases are miscible? Or does miscible in this case refer to a chemical reaction?